# View / Embed (PDF, PPT, Video) file in web page with security

Tags: pdf, video, embed, powerpoint

I am creating a web page which has Video, Study Material in PDF or PPT format.

I want to secure all the Videos, PDF & PPT's, the user cannot download or save it.
And also all the file are stored on my server not on another.

i know Slideshare.net or youtube video embed etc... i guess all this are not secure.

Is there any plugin or any mechanism where my feature are fulfilled??

Comment: User cannot download or save it? But why? Can't the user just screenshot the PDF/PPT pages? Or record the Video playing using a screen recorder?

Comment: @Lotus92 its like paid videos or pdf's, for those user who has bought it. and yes you are right they can record a video using recorder but rather doing pressing ctrl+s or view page source.....